# How much does it take to run report OBIEE?

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

Is it possible to show runtime of OBIEE report on the dashboard? For example, if it takes 10 sec. to run one particular report, then I want to display 10 sec. on the dashboard for that report.

Comment: Setting up usage tracking can help you to analyze how long previously it took to run a specific report, but it won't provide info about actual report execution as there is no data yet. And as Chris tells - it might vary depending on multiple  
circumstances. Specific report execution details can be found also in Sessions under Administration (if you have access to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as OBI is a fully dynamic analytical platform and queries can wildly change on the user logged on, the current variables in play, security, change a prompt, switch out a column etc etc etc...

It's not a reporting tool. It's analytics

Comment: Edit: Just if it wasn't clear enough. No, that isn't really a feasible idea!